# Remove filter from a specific part of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use a filter to make my background image black and white, and would like to remove it at a specific part of the page (see picture below) using Bootstrap. How to do that in CSS ?

HTML :

```
    <div class="section bg-cover">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="color" class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-4 img-rounded">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <!-- text here -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS :

```
    .bg-cover {
        background: url('img/bg1.jpg') no-repeat center center; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
        filter: grayscale(100%);
    }

    #color { /* COLOR HERE !! */
        border: 3px solid;
        height:60vh;
    }
```

Result picture (The color should be inside the square) : https://puu.sh/pl8GC/2f7f15c0a8.jpg

Comment: No this is not possible. `filter` applies to the parent and all children. It's like `opacity' in that way.

Comment: I see... Is there a way of doing a similar effect without filter ?

Comment: Not that I can think of.

Comment: That's unfortunate... Then I guess I will just use photoshop for the black and white effect and put two different background... Thanks for your help anyway !

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a solution so I post it here : I had to put the background in a div with no children as the filter property spreads to all the children of it's div, and then use background-clip to put an other background on it at the right location.